# access to a void* variable with ccall and unsafe_load

Tags: c, embedded, julia

I'm trying to implement a Julia Wrapper for a C API I'm using. For instance : I've got the following prototype :

`int32 foo(int32 BrdType, int32 BrdNumber, Bd *pBrdHandle)`.

Base on the source code the definition of `Bd` is `typedef void ***Bd;`
`Bd` will then be used later to manipulate my hardware (for instance with `int32 otherfoo(Bd BrdHandle)`)

---

### What I tried in julia

Currently, I can call my foo function in julia, but I'm not able to deference my pointer...

```
function fooWrap()
    #function Pointer
    lib = dlopen(find_library("foo.dll"))
    func = dlsym(lib, "foo")
    #Argument
    BrdType = -1
    BrdNumber = 0
    pBrdHandle = Ref{Ptr{Cvoid}}()
    #Output
    result = ccall(func, Cint, (Cint, Cint, Ptr{Cvoid}), BrdType, BrdNumber, pBrdHandle)
    println("result : ", result)
    BrdHandle = unsafe_load(pBrdHandle)
    return BrdHandle
end
```

(NB : the `unsafe_load` function gave me the following error :

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching unsafe_load(::Base.RefValue{Ptr{Nothing}})
Closest candidates are:
  unsafe_load(::Ptr) at pointer.jl:105
  unsafe_load(::Ptr, ::Integer) at pointer.jl:105
```

So how should I do to "transform" my `pBrdHandle` into `BrdHandle` ?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

---

#### EDIT

For clarity purpose, here are the "real" signature of the function :

`BIRC BiBrdOpen(BFU32 BrdType, BFU32 BrdNumber, Bd *pBrdHandle)`

`BIRC BiBrdClose(Bd Board)`

with `typedef unsigned __int32    BFU32;`, `typedef BFU32 BFRC;` and `typedef void ***Bd;`

Comment: `pBrdHandle = Ref{Ptr{Cvoid}}()` why do you need a reference to a pointer? you can just use a pointer I guess.

Comment: I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140699/the-proper-way-to-declare-c-void-pointers-in-julia) to make my declaration. Otherwise, I had an error when calling `ccall`

Comment: I see. try `unsafe_load(pBrdHandle[])` then?

Comment: not working either...
`print(pBrdHandle)` gave me `Base.RefValue{Ptr{Nothing}}(Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000054548fe0`
and `BrdHandle = unsafe_load(pBrdHandle[])` gave `BrdHandle::Nothing = nothing`

Comment: This question is hard to answer without actual signatures for the C functions. Are you sure that the signature for `int32 otherfoo(Bd BrdHandle)` is not `int32 otherfoo(Bd *BrdHandle)`, for example? It's pretty unusual for opaque handles to be passed as pointers in some functions and dereferenced in others.

Comment: "the definition of Bd is typedef void ***Bd;" Great, so you get a `void****pBrdHandle`. The solution in this case is to toss this code in the garbage and rewrite it from scratch. Whoever wrote it was obviously completely incompetent - you cannot salvage this code.

Comment: Unfortunately yes I'm sure that the signature is `int 32 otherfoo(Bd BrdHandle)` and unfortunately, the code is an API of a very specific hardware I cannot toss it (for now..)
NB : I edited the Signature C functions for clarity.

Comment: But there's chance that the hardware is of the same non-existing quality as the software. When I google this I get hits on medical devices...  if that's the case, then this library is literally criminal

Comment: Actually, it is for a frame grabber

Comment: @Lundin : Could you briefly explain me why do you think this code is garbage ? (expecially the void **** part)

Comment: Summary: https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer Basically, people who write code as complicated as they possibly can are very bad programmers. The truly skilled programmers are those who write code as simple as possible.

Comment: `Bd` is just a pointer to some opaque type. It would be clearer this way: `typedef struct Opaque *Bd;`